# how can i create a modal by remote and initial textbox in the same function using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

### script.js

```
function change_val(){
    $("#remoteModal2").modal({
        remote:"modals/edit_text_value.html",
        show:true
     });
     $("#my_textbox").val("this is a text")

}
```

### index.html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="remoteModal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="remoteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">  
     <div class="modal-dialog">  
         <div class="modal-content">

         </div>  
     </div>  
</div>

<button onclick="change_val()" >show modal</button>
```

### edit_text_value.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
  header
</div>  

<div class="modal-body">
   <textarea id="my_textbox"></textarea>
</div> 

<div class="modal-footer">  
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>  
</div>
```

---

The problem is that I **must run it twice to  make it work !**

How to do all the operations in a function ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`shown.bs.modal` OR `show.bs.modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

**When we use this code :**

```
.on('shown.bs.modal')
```

.

```
$('#remoteModal2').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("#my_textbox").val("this is a new text);
    return e.preventDefault();
});
```

1. import modal (remote "edit_text_value.html")
2. Open modal
3. After the completion of loading and effects , change value..
4. show new value...

**But this code :**

> `.on('show.bs.modal')`

Apply the changes ,Before reading the tags and remote the modal...

Therefore, it is not effective.

Because it can not find this ID (#my_textbox) Before remote modal page!

[***more information...***](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)